# How to fix not started response in Microsoft speaker recognization API

Tags: python-3.x, azure-cognitive-services

When i am running the Microsoft speaker recognization API **(Speaker Recognition - Get Operation Status)**
I am getting this response

Case 1 - not started
HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
Content-Type: application/json
{
"status": "notstarted",
"createdDateTime":  "2015-09-30T01:28:23Z",
"lastActionDateTime": "2015-09-30T01:29:23Z"
}

How to get rid of this response?

Answer (score 0):

The response "**notstarted**" is a normal response from the api, it means the enrollment hasn’t completed. We just need to wait and the response will be "**running**" and then "**succeeded**". You can refer to this [tutorial](https://www.robinosborne.co.uk/2018/10/08/ai-awesomeness-part-deux-microsoft-cognitive-services-speaker-identification/) about it.

[image]

Comment: i am not enrolling the profile I am checking the operation status, i am following this tutorial https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/5645c725ca73070ee8845bd6

while running the code 50% of time i am getting Case 1 - not started and rest 50% of time i am getting Case 5.2.1: Identification Result.

i always want Case 5.2.1 but i am not getting it.

(I am using Microsoft Free Speaker API) and doing 1 API call / minute